# 403 Forbidden after Github Action

Tags: laravel-8, github-actions, http-status-code-403

I have an Laravel 8 Api application that was running 100% in a shared vps hosting.
Everything was fine, then I add a github action in order to do a simple CD/CI using the https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action.
Since then, something was happened to all my directories permissions, so I having a 403 Forbidden HTTP Error message in all the API endpoints.

Can someone help me in this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [`SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action`](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/209) is not suppose to change file permission, the root cause should be:

- either some [config cache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777580/6309)
- some [missing bearer token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841479/6309)
- a [missing custom request class `authorize()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235450/6309)

Checking [the logs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging) should help narrowing the possible issues.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, but the problem occurs even in login route (where there is not a bearer token). I have already cleaned all cache. And everything was perfectly ok before the github action.

Comment: @Fabiano OK. I would try and reproduce the issue. Get back to a state of the application (*not* deployed by GitHub action but manually) where everything works. Then run again the GitHub Action, this time with some `ls -alrth` on remote server folders before and after the sftp deployment. Basically to try and spot what change between a manually installed app, and the same app deployed through GitHub Action.